# WebClient wait operation - Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I've read that the communications are asynchronous WP7 but there are cases that do not lack this type of communication.

I am using webclient to download content and just want to go to the next operation, after receiving such content.

How is this done?

I'm a noob on this platform.

Cumpz

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a synchronous method. If that is the case, you can do something like this:

```
        AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(ar => waitHandle.Set(), null);
        if (!waitHandle.WaitOne(30000))
        {
            throw new TimeoutException("Timed out");
        }
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult) as HttpWebResponse)
        {
          ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code which will help you get started using the WebClient class

Create the WebClient

```
WebClient client = new WebClient())
                client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
                client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
```

Now, do something once the download string operation has finished

```
        void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Result;
        // Do something with the string
        DoThingWithString(result)
    }
```

Comment: It is, it inherits from Component (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx)
However in a Windows Phone 7 context, it does not :)